# Software to search for Youtube videos, given a search pattern

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, youtube, scraping

I wonder if exists a software that, given a search pattern like for example a song title, it can search for youtube videos and return the video urls of the search results.

The application should expose in a friendly way the Youtube urls of the found videos (to copy those urls in the clipboard), when more automation in this kind of feature, it will be better for my needs (like for example an option saying "*Copy the url of all results to clipboard*").

I don't care if the software could download, play, or convert videos, anyways that kind of additional features are welcome, but I'm only interested in a good Youtube searcher that looks for videos matching the whole or part of a search pattern string, then return in some way the urls of the videos found.

Requisites:

- A desktop application for Windows O.S.
- Command-line or graphical user interface.
- Free and/or open-source solutions preferred.

  Paid solutions only in case it does not costs too much (lets say around $30).

Optional requests:

- Multiple searchs at once.

  To understand: For example letting the user put various search patterns (various song titles) in a textbox then search for results of every pattern.
- CLI interface to automate searchs.

Answer (score 0):

**[Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)**

It is the official Google API to do this, Here is it's [documentation for search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list). I don't fully understand what is a search pattern: The API can search for strings and YouTube *of course will send* results of the same *pattern* of the search string you gave. You can further make another piece of software to make individual *search strings* by your *search pattern* and get all the videos from different searches and combine them.

In the YouTube API site, you will be presented with a "try it!" window. More on it: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer.

*[[youtube-data-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) and [[youtube-api]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) in Stack Overflow.*

Comment: This isn't a good answer because the question ask for a program, not for a library. The Youtube API certainly does what's requested..... in the hands of a developer. The question doesn't gives any hint about the OP being willing or able to program it himself. See [Asking for software, get libraries in answers](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/428/asking-for-software-get-libraries-in-answers).

Comment: @Alejandro Yes, as you said, OP has not given details of doesn't gives any hint about the OP being willing or able to program it himself, nor he states he wants an app (sure desktop but with CLI, it is not necessary to be a .exe, you can just build the URL and run). The only way to depict what workflow OP requires is the actual request: *looks for videos matching the whole or part of a search pattern string, then return some way the urls of the videos found..* He says command line interface or GUI, so CLI + no app, win win.